# Error handling - Consumer - apache kafka and spring

Tags: spring, error-handling, apache-kafka

I am learning to use kafka, I have two services a producer and a consumer.

The producer produces messages that require processing (queries to services and database). These messages are received by the consumer, it is responsible for processing them and saves the result in a database

Producer

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
...
kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
```

Consumer

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "....")
public void listen(@Payload String message) {
....
}
```

I would like all messages to be processed correctly by the consumer.
I do not know how to handle errors on the consumer side in this context. For example, a database might be temporarily disabled and could not handle certain messages.

What to do in these cases?

I know that the responsibility belongs to the consumer.
I could do retries, but retry several times in a row if a database is down does not seem like a good idea. And if I continue to consume messages, the index advances and I lose the events that I could not process by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link was very helpful https://dzone.com/articles/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-han

Spring provides the DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer class that performs a correct handling of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You have control over kafka consumer in form of committing the offset of records read. Kafka will continue to return the same records unless the offset is committed. You can set offset commit to manual and based on the success of your business logic decide whether to commit or not. See a sample below

```
Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
 props.put("group.id", "test");
 props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
 consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
 final int minBatchSize = 200;
 List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         buffer.add(record);
     }
     if (buffer.size() >= minBatchSize) {
         insertIntoDb(buffer);
         consumer.commitSync();
         buffer.clear();
     }
 }
```

Consumer.commitsync() commits the offset.

Also see the kakfa consumer documentation to understand the consumer offsets [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) .

Comment: even if the consumer does not commit, it will read on the next message. The commit part happens when the consumer dies and comes up again. If the consumer never dies it will go on reading the next message irrespective of you commit or not